# elif block not executing in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

What is wrong here? Upon entering 3 (<=5), the output should be, I think, "Phew, ..." but it stays as "Awesome, ..."

```
weather = raw_input('How is the weather today, from 0 to 10? ')
answer = raw_input ('Are you in mood to go out? ')
if weather >= 5:
    if answer == 'Yes':
        print 'Awesome, I will go out!'
        print 'Will you come with me?'
    else:
        print 'Awesome, I am going out now!'
elif weather <= 5:
    print "Phew, I didn't want to go outside, great, I will stay in! Thank God!"
else:
    print "Huh?"
```

Comment: ```raw_input``` returns a string - you are comparing a string to an integer in your conditional statements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string not an integer, e.g. `'3'` instead of `3`.

In Python 2, strings always compare greater than integers so `weather >= 5` is always true.

To fix this, cast `weather` to an integer:

```
weather = int(raw_input('How is the weather today, from 0 to 10? '))
```

Answer (score 2):

raw_input returns a string and you need to convert it to integer.

```
weather = int(raw_input('How is the weather today, from 0 to 10? '))
```

And you need to catch any exceptions for handling wrong inputs.